# Facebook ACCESS_TOKEN used with links.getStats

Tags: facebook, access-token

links.getStats was working fine as simple REST call just few weeks ago, and right now it's failing... The reason is simple, it needs an ACCESS_TOKEN.

Of course, my application, which I use to stream some content to my wall, has an non expiring (offline usage) access token. But if I try to use this token with links.getStats I get this error: "Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API".

So my question would be: How could I get a valid ACCESS_TOKEN, that I could successfully call links.getStats?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We're tracking this issue internally. Here's the bug id: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19470

The workaround solution is to use any user access token with the call. You're trying to use an app or page access token, which won't work. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ , get an access token for yourself, and tack that onto the call with `&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` and it will work.